# What does the "penetrate" stat do?

Tags: greedy-cave

I wonder what this stat does in Greedy Cave. Is that a sort of armor penetration, lowering the armor of your opponent by your total penetrate amount? What is the math behind this?

[image]

Comment: If the armor values in the game is not really high (400-500 for that level for example) it should be a stat that just removes X from the enemy's armor stat when calculating damage. If the armor values are high, it's probably a percentage unless you can have multiple of this stat to go over 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The penetrate stat does remove the stat amount to the defense stat of the opponent before applying the weapon damages.

Let's take the weapon on your screen and let's imagine the defense of the opponent is 200. You would remove 44 to this initial defense stat, leaving 156 points in defense. Assuming that nothing more is giving you points in the attack stat, your attack will then do between 56 (212 - 156) and 325 (481 - 156) damages to the opponent.

Do note that the penetrate stat do not add damages to your attack stat if the opponent's defense is too weak. Let's take another exemple. If the opponent defense stat is 20, your penetration will reduce the stat to 0. But the 24 unused points of the penetrate stat won't be added to the attack stat. They just affect the defense stat of the opponent. So your attack will inflict between 212 and 481 damages (still assuming you don't have any other bonus for damages).

Comment: So what you're telling, is that the "penetrate" stat is _almost_ identical to the "attack" stat, the difference being the case where the opponent's defense amount is lower than the penetrate amount ?

Comment: Well, they are nearly working the same way. If there was no penetration, you usually just remove your attack stat to the defense stat of the opponent to get the final possible range of damages. With the penetrate stat however, you do lower that defense amount BEFORE using the attack stat. And if the opponent's armor is lowered to 0, you won't get additional damages. But you will hit without any reduction from the defense stat.